# SharePoint ProcessBatchData Update: nativehr 0x80070057

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Annoying and unhelpful error: `<nativehr>0x80070057</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>` when running SPWeb.ProcessBatchUpdate...no inner exception or anything else useful. Here is the XMl that is being sent:

```
<ows:Batch OnError="Return">

    <Method ID="1">
        <SetList>9efe6671-d8e1-4da5-9b59-3404e57e7347</SetList>
        <SetVar Name="Cmd">Save</SetVar>
        <SetVar Name="ID">1</SetVar>

        <SetVar Name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Title">OK</SetVar>
    </Method>
</ows:Batch>
```

I have checked out this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc404818(v=office.12).aspx
and many, many others. I have tried using Scope="Request" on the SetList element just in case, but also no luck. What could I possibly be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that I had an empty line above the `<batch>` element... and when I removed it, all started behaving again...very perculiar that it can't handle such a small thing as a "\r\n" on the first line...   :-|

Comment: I just found another reason: XML attributes MUST be delimited by double quotes, NOT single quotes. I'd `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>` and MUST be `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`